# what is the opposite of IsNothing?

Tags: vba

I want to say `If the field "Resource" holds a value" ... then` basically the opposite of

`IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Resource.Value)`

can you please help

Comment: Where in the world did you find a IsNothing() function in VBA ???

Comment: @iDevlop Good point actually, didn't clock the tag there.

Comment: Plus I presume you mean IF not IFF which has two arguments.

Comment: The opposite of anything is not anything

Answer (score 12):

Just add `NOT`:

```
If Not IsNothing(something) Then ...
```

**EDIT :**

Having just seen the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) tag,

```
Dim myVariable as Object    
If Not myVariable Is Nothing Then ...
```

Comment: 10 votes for a nonsense answer to a wrong question. SO should create a badge for this ! (and I confess i am jealous :)

Comment: @iDevlop With the exception of the poorly-named `something` in the first example, where's the "nonsense" in my answer? I agree, it's surprising that 10 people bothered to vote at all, but that's their choice!

Comment: The nonsense is that IsNothing() does not exist, And for the second part, `Is Nothing` cannot be used to check if a field "holds a value". One must use `Is NUll` for that.

Comment: @iDevlop Yep, it's a bit confusing. I've answered the first question, "what is the opposite of IsNothing?".

Comment: -1 I must agree with @iDevelop. Including the badge Edward Lear badge perhaps? I will allow IsEmpty for an object, but IsNothing is nothing indeed.

Comment: @Remou Yep, seems like there's some debate about my answer as to whether 'twas brillig or mimsy.

Answer (score 2):

A very efficient way to check a value exists is to check it's length:

```vb
If Len(Fields!Resource.Value) <> 0
```

Comment: It's not the best trend if you ask me - its slightly faster to check for inequality.

Comment: Its faster again  - albeit slightly - with LenB rather than Len. But I prefer (without good reason) the more common >0 to inequality, probably habbit

Comment: LenB was slightly faster - but as far as I can tell from MS documentation, they no longer support LenB. "All current Visual Basic strings are in Unicode, and LenB is no longer supported."

Comment: This is chancy with nulls: `a=null ↵ ?len(a)<>0 ↵ Null` You would need say, `Trim(Fields!Resource.Value & "") = vbNullString` to cover ZLS, space-filled and null.

Comment: Space filled shouldn't be considered 'nothing'. :)

Comment: True, but it often is, and can lead to a good deal of confusion when you debug.print the field :)

Answer (score 2):

IsNothing() does NOT exist in VBA. To check if a field or a variant contains something, you should use
 `If myField Is NUll then`

To check for unassigned objects, use

```
If myObject Is Nothing Then
```